# Adding String to a list in Java

Tags: java

Please have a look at the below code snippet.
I had a look at some solutions provided on stackoverflow for adding String to a list.
They did not work out well in the below case.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/EmployeeDept/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
// ResponseEntity is meant to represent the entire HTTP response
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDeptResponse> getDept()
{
    EmployeeDeptResponse deptResponse = new EmployeeDeptResponse();
    HttpStatus httpStatus;
    List<EmployeeDept> employeeDeptList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDept>();

    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
                "http://localhost:8082/rest/EmployeeDept/");
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
        String output;

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            employeeDeptList.add(output);
        }

        deptResponse.setItems(employeeDeptList);
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
    return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeDeptResponse>(deptResponse,httpStatus);

}
```

I am getting an error in the while loop as "add in list can not be applied to java.lang.String"

The list of type "EmployeeDept".The EmployeeDept class looks like this:-

```
package com.springboot.postrgres.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class EmployeeDept implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int id;
private String dept;


public EmployeeDept() {
}

public EmployeeDept(int id, String dept) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dept = dept;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDept() {
    return dept;
}

public void setDept(String name) {
    this.dept = dept;
}
```

}

In the above code I have a list "employeeDeptList" and a string "Output".
I need to add this string to the list.

Can any of you provide suitable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a String cannot be added to a `List<EmployeeDept>`.

Comment: Yes..But how to solve this problem?

Comment: What Eran said.  You have a list of `EmployeeDept` objects.  What are you trying to accomplish by adding a string to this list?  Are you trying to add an `EmployeeDept` and somehow have one automatically created from a `String`?  Or do you want a list that mostly contains `EmployeeDept` objects but has an occasional `String` in it just to be different?  Or what?

Comment: [Square peg in a round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole)

Comment: You can change like this `EmployeeDept empdept = new EmployeeDept();
empDept.setDept(output) 
 employeeDeptList.add(empdept);`instead of ` employeeDeptList.add(output);`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes I understand it is a square peg in round hole.You may want to suggest an answer or may want me to change my strategy.What matters as of now is the output.What strategy I use is not that important.

Comment: your question has the answer itself. `I am getting an error in the while loop as "add in list can not be applied to java.lang.String"

The list of type "EmployeeDept"`

Comment: @KaustubhLonkar what is your `output` values contains ? it just a dept name ?

Comment: @ajb What Eran said is absolutely correct.I am aware of this fact.I just need to show the output in browser.Previously I had a different code snippet which would show the output in the browser.But not in the way I expect.{
success: true,
items: [
{
id: 2,
name: "Wilson",
designation: "Developer"
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Wilson",
designation: "Developer"
}
],
errorMessage: null
}.I want to get it in this way.

Comment: And what does this expected output have to do with reading a string from an input stream?

Comment: @soorapadman This is what is displayed in the console as well as browser.      {"1499921014230":{"id":1499921014230,"dept":"mechanics"},"1499921019747":{"id":1499921019747,"dept":"civil"}}

Comment: @KaustubhLonkar you are getting `empdept` obj as a response so you can parse the string and create the obj then add to the list.

Comment: Are the lines you're reading from the input stream JSON objects?  If they are, you will need to convert them from strings to `EmployeeDept` using a JSON parser.  This conversion doesn't take place automatically.  You have to tell the computer that's what you want to do, by putting it in your program.  It can't read your mind.

Comment: @KaustubhLonkar can you follow `ajb` comments . That is what you need to do .

Comment: @ajb will try to do that.Thanks for suggestion.I hope that should work.

Comment: @soorapadman sure..I think that would solve the issue.Lemme try it.

Answer (score 1):

`employeeDeptList` is of type `ArrayList<EmployeeDept>`.

```
List<EmployeeDept> employeeDeptList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDept>();
```

`output` on the other hand is of type `String`

```
String output;
```

So when you do `employeeDeptList.add(output);`, you are trying to add a `String` to your `employeeDeptList`, when it should be an `EmployeeDept`.

So you either make `output` an `EmployeeDept` or you rethink what you want to do with it.

As a suggestion, I am going to assume that your `output` should contain the information you need to create an EmployeeDept. You probably want to parse that information and create a `EmployeeDept dept = new EmployeeDept(parsedId, parsedDept);` and then add it to `employeeDeptList` as `employeeDeptList.add(dept);`

Comment: Thanks But that did not work.I need to adopt some other means.

Answer (score 0):

employeeDeptList is a list of EmployeeDept object. You are trying to add a String to the list of EmployeeDept. Which is not posssible unless you change the type of output variable to EmployeeDept.

Comment: Did that too.But it did not work.Tried with casting to list also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code.

```
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        employeeDeptList.add(output);
    }
```

`output` is a String and you are trying to add that to a `List<EmployeeDept>`. You can't do that. If you want to add `output` to a List, you should create a List of Strings. Something like `List<String>`

As you mentioned, what you are getting is,

> {
>       "1499921014230": {
>           "id": 1499921014230,
>           "dept": "mechanics"
>       },
>       "1499921019747": {
>           "id": 1499921019747,
>           "dept": "civil"
>       }
>   }

If you can change that , you can try to change it to a simple array of objects,

> [
>       {
>           "id": 1499921014230,
>           "dept": "mechanics"
>       },
>       {
>           "id": 1499921019747,
>           "dept": "civil"
>       }
>   ]

Add below dependency if you use maven, or just add the .jar to the lib,

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>`

Then try something like this,

```
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(output);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

        String dept = jsonObj.getString("dept");
        int id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
        System.out.println("id : " + id + "    dept : " + dept);

        employeeDeptList.add(new EmployeeDept(id, dept));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct the problem is with the code.I need to tweak it.I tried casting output to list but it did not work.Earlier I had something else.I mean a different code that gave me the following output in the terminal as well as the browser.    {"1499921014230":{"id":1499921014230,"dept":"mechanics"},"1499921019747":{"id":1499921019747,"dept":"civil"}}

Comment: Use the info (`id` and `dept`) you have to create the `EmployeeDept` object. And add that object to the `employeeDeptList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you response is a valid json (specified header), why won't you try to map it to objects?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//assuming your response entity content is a list of objects (json array, since you specified header 'application/json'
String jsonArray = String theString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), encoding);
employeeDeptList  = List<Employee> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, employeeDeptList.class));

//assuming your response is a single object
String json = String theString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), encoding);
employeeDeptList.add(mapper.readValue(json, Employee.class));

//assuming every line of content is an object (does not really make sense)
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ew InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
String output;

while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    employeeDeptList.add(mapper.readValue(output, Employee.class));
}
```